# text input, select and radio buttons and how to change value of 'price' within a div query?

Tags: jquery, forms, select, input

I have a text input that holds the number of articles, a drop down that represents the type of article and two radio buttons that represent yes or no whether the user would like an expert or not.
So:

```
    <input class="form-control" type="text" name="article_number" id="article_number">
    <select class="form-control" name="scribbles" id="scribbles">
    <option id='49' value='standard_blog_post'>Standard Blog Post</option>
    <option id='59' value='long_blog_post'>Long Blog Post</option>
    <option id='69' value='website_page'>Website Page</option>
    <option id='299' value='white_paper'>White Paper</option>
    <option id='50' value='tweets'>Tweets</option>
    <option id='75' value='facebook_posts'>Facebook Posts</option>
    <option id='49' value='email_newsletter'>Email Newsletter</option>
    <option id='149' value='press_release'>Press Release</option>
    <option id='199' value='video_script'>Video Script</option>
    </select>
    <input type="radio" name="expert" value="yes">Yes I Need An Expert<br>
    <input type="radio" name="expert" value="no">No I don't need An Expert
    <div id="finalprice"></div>
```

I have made the id's of the select drop down the 'price' of each type of associated article.  An expert doubles the price of each article type.  How would you use all of this information to display the price in the final price div, based on all of the variables I have listed above?

Comment: OK, your HTML is cool, now where's the jQuery you tried? (sidenote: numeric ID is only valid in HTML5...)

Comment: You forgot to post the JavaScript you tried.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With your existing HTML here's a jQuery script that gives you what you want.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#scribbles, [name="expert"]').on("change", showPrice);
});

function showPrice() {
    var price = $("#scribbles option:selected").attr('id');
    if ($('[name="expert"]:checked').val() === "yes")
        price *= 2;
    $("#finalprice").text(price);
}
```

Fiddle [here](http://jsfiddle.net/y44p6h6p/)